# Is adding a trait method with implementation breaking backward compatibility?

Tags: scala, binary-compatibility, migration-manager

I am confused regarding backward compatibility when adding a method *with default implementation* to a trait. Like:

**Previous Version**

```
trait Foo
```

**New Version**

```
trait Foo {
  def verifyConsistency: Option[String] = ??? // provide default implementation
}
```

The [Migration Manager](https://github.com/typesafehub/migration-manager) reports this addition as a binary incompatibility. Is that correct?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Well yes it is correct.

When you define trait `Foo`, it will under the hood create both a (JVM) interface `Foo` and a (JVM) class `Foo$class` with all the method implementations defined as static methods. The corresponding java code would look like something like this (for your new defintion of `Foo`):

```
interface Foo {
  Option<String> verifyConsistency();
}

class Foo$class {
  static Option<String> verifyConsistency(Foo self) {
    Predef.???();
  }
}
```

When you mix `Foo` into a concrete class `Bar`, what happens at the JVM level is that `Bar` extends the interface `Foo`, and it implements method `verifyConsistency` by simply forwarding the call to `Foo$class`:

```
class Bar implements Foo {
  Option<String> verifyConsistency() {
    return Foo$class.verifyConsistency(this); // simple forwarding
  }
}
```

The reason why it is done this way is that the JVM object model does not support multiple inheritance. The traits implementations cannot be simply put in classes that you would extend from, because you can only ever extend a single class on the JVM.

The take away of this situation is that everytime a concrete class mixes a trait, the class defines "stub" methods for each member of the trait (those methods simply forward to the actual implementation, which is a static method).

One consequence is that if you add a new method to a trait, even if you define an implementation it is not enough: concrete classes that mix the trait need to be recompiled (so that a stub for the new method is added to the class). If you don't recompile those classes, your program will fail to run, as you would now have a class that is supposedly concrete (non abstract) AND extend the corresponding interface but actually miss the implementation for the new method.

In your case this means having concrete classes that extend interface `Foo` but do not have any implementation for `verifyConsistency`.

Hence the binary incompatibility.

Comment: Ok thanks. I thought the whole ceremony around traits was that you could add methods and as long as you provide a default implementation you do _not_ have to recompile everything. So I guess I was wrong there :-(