# Scala IntList to Java

Tags: java, scala

So I have this Scala function which returns a IntList

```scala
def drawLine(x0: Int, y0: Int, x1: Int, y1: Int): IntList = {
  val list : IntList = drawLineRec(x0, y0, x1, y1, Math.abs(x1-x0), -Math.abs(y1-y0), Math.abs(x1-x0)-Math.abs(y1-y0))
  println("\nline: "+list)
  return list
}
```

I now want to use it over in my java file, where I call this function and get the return

```java
CalcDraw.IntList drawLine = newDraw.drawLine(x0, y0, x1, y1);
```

Is there a way to run through this IntList in java, because I tried to use `for` or `foreach`, but without any luck.

The return call contains something like this:

`Cons((20,20),Cons((21,21),Nil()))`

*EDIT with more info*

So here is a simplified Scala code:

```scala
class CalcDraw { // ctrl + shift+ b to evaluate.

    sealed abstract class IntList;
    case class Nil() extends IntList;
    case class Cons(hd: (Int,Int), tl: IntList) extends IntList;

    def concat(list1: IntList, list2: IntList) : IntList = list1 match{
      //concatenates two lists
      case Nil() => list2
      case Cons(head,tail) => Cons(head,concat(tail,list2))
    }
    def concatIf(list1: IntList, list2: IntList, predicate: ()=>Boolean) : IntList = if(predicate()){
      concat(list1,list2)
    }else{
      return list1
    }

    /*
    *
    *  LINE DRAWING
    *
    */

    def next(x0: Int, x1: Int): Int = if(x0 < x1) x0 + 1 else x0 - 1

    def drawLineRec(x0: Int, y0: Int, x1: Int, y1: Int, dx: Int, dy: Int, err: Int): IntList = {
      if(!(x0 == x1 && y0 == y1))
      {
        if((2*err) >= dy)
        {
          if((2*err) <= dx)
          {
            // Change in both x and y0
            Cons((x0, y0), drawLineRec(next(x0, x1), next(y0, y1), x1, y1, dx, dy, err + dx + dy))
          }
          else
          {
            // Change only in x0
            Cons((x0, y0), drawLineRec(next(x0, x1), y0, x1, y1, dx, dy, err + dy))
          }
        }
        else if((2*err) <= dx) {
          // Change only in y0
          Cons((x0, y0), drawLineRec(x0, next(y0, y1), x1, y1, dx, dy, err + dx))
        } else{
          Nil() // This should not happen, so maybe this is an incorrect approach
        }
      } else{
        Cons((x0, y0), Nil())
      }
    }

    def drawLine(x0: Int, y0: Int, x1: Int, y1: Int): IntList = {
      val list : IntList = drawLineRec(x0, y0, x1, y1, Math.abs(x1-x0), -Math.abs(y1-y0), Math.abs(x1-x0)-Math.abs(y1-y0))
      println("\nline: "+list)
      return list
    }

  }
```

the java part is just as simple as calling the function

```java
CalcDraw.IntList drawLine = newDraw.drawLine(x0, y0, x1, y1);
```

Comment: Why do you want to calm this code from **Java** that `IntList` is jus a simplified collection to learn. In real programs you should be using the collections provided in the stdlib and if interacting with **Java** then convert them to **Java** collections using the `JavaConverters`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```java
CalcDraw calcDraw = new CalcDraw();
CalcDraw.IntList l = calcDraw.drawLine(1, 2, 3, 4);
while (l instanceof CalcDraw.Cons) {
    CalcDraw.Cons cons = (CalcDraw.Cons) l;
    System.out.println(cons.hd());
    l = cons.tl();
}
```

In addition, please read [Return in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12560463/2359227), which shouldn't be used here. You can drop the semicolons. And you probably want to define `IntList` as `sealed trait`. You can read more about it at [Difference between using sealed trait and sealed abstract class as a base class](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41078797/2359227)

Comment: @Tomer_Shetah, is it possible for you to explain to me what exactly the while loop does? I've never really done it like this before :)

Comment: @MeNoLonely, Sure I can, but I think it is pretty straight forward. Can you please tell me what don't you understand?

Comment: When you have a while with `instanceof` what does that do? and I think I understand the rest, `CalcDraw.Cons cons = (CalcDraw.Cons) lists` gets all the cons, and then I just get the `(x, y)` values from `hd: (int, int)` like you told me `cons.hd()`

Comment: @MeNoLonely it checks the type of `l`. It might be either `CalcDraw.Cons` or `CalcDraw.Nil`. If it is the first, it means we can extract the head. Once we got to `CalcDraw.Nil`, there are no more items, and we stop the loop. Does that make sense for you?

Comment: @MeNoLonely, I've answered your other question. Is my answer helpful for you?