# Ensure that the type parameter for my trait is a Monad

Tags: scala

I have written this code

```
trait Input[F[_]] {
    def read: F[String]
    def write(str: String) : F[Unit]
    def getName : F[String] = for {
        _ <- write("What is your name")
        name <- read
    } yield name
}
```

This code doesn't compile obviously because the compiler has no way of knowing that the type F supports flatmap. So I change my code to

```
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._
trait Input[F[_] : Monad] {
    def read: F[String]
    def write(str: String) : F[Unit]
    def getName : F[String] = for {
        _ <- write("What is your name")
        name <- read
    } yield name
}
```

but now I get compile time error `traits cannot have type parameters with context bounds`.

So how can I specify constraints on my type parameter so that it always supports flatmap?

Comment: As has been noted: "traits can't have constructor parameters," but an `abstract class` can, and there are a few other reasons you might [prefer an abstract class instead of a trait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35251513/4993128).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`trait Input[F[_]: Monad]` would create an implicit constructor parameter and traits can't have constructor parameters (until Scala 3). `def testFunc[F[_]: Monad]` would create an implicit parameter. For instance:

```
def testFunc[F[_]: Monad](arg: Int) = ???
class TestClass[F[_]: Monad] {}
```

Will work because it is translated to:

```
def testFunc[F[_]](arg: Int)(implicit ev: Monad[F]) = ???
class TestClass[F[_]](implicit val ev: Monad[F]) {}
```

I.e. `[F[_]: Monad]` is syntactic sugar for `[F[_]]` with `implicit val ev: Monad[F]`. And traits has no constructor to pass parameters until Scala 3.

For your case, if you really need to inside a trait to constraint `F` to a `Monad` for example, then:

```
trait Input[F[_]] {
  val M: Monad[F]

  def read: F[String]
  def write(str: String) : F[Unit]
  def getName : F[String] = M.flatMap(write("What is your name"))(_ => read)
}
```

I.e. you are saying to one who implements, that "you can implement `Input`, as soon as you have `Monad[F]`". Then you can use it like:

```
object Main extends App{

  class IOInput extends Input[IO] {
    override val M: Monad[IO] = Monad[IO]
    override def read: IO[String] = IO("red")
    override def write(str: String): IO[Unit] = IO(println(s"write: $str"))
  }

  val impl = new IOInput

  println(impl.getName.unsafeRunSync())
}
```

P.S. But for me, it seems like something is wrong. You are kinda defining effects in trait `Input` and using them right in the same trait. Reads weird for me at least. Probably `getName` should be somewhere else.

Comment: The problem is not "Because constraints work on actual implementations." It's just that `trait Input[F[_]: Monad]` would create an implicit constructor parameter and traits can't have constructor parameters (until Scala 3).